# How does MySQL run as user "_mysql" on Mac?

Tags: mysql, setuid

On Mac, MySQL seems to save data as the "_mysql" user. Can somebody please explain how this is achieved. I would have expected the MySQL server application (mysqld) to have the setuid flag set, so that it would run as _mysql, but this isn't the case. How, then, does it somehow run as "_mysql"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a wide variety of ways this can be accomplished, but the two most common are:

1. Processes started as root can change their user id to any other user on the system through their own internal programming; most daemons including MySQL operate this way.
2. Processes can be started with `sudo -u _mysql mysqld` or it's rough equivalent.

Comment: Thanks Chris. In relation to (1), would this be through system-specific APIs? I'm wondering how you go about this in C or Java.

Comment: setuid() and friends in C

Comment: Directions for calling setuid() from Java: http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/Java/archives/0510/Silverman/index.html